# maven не может качать зависимостей

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, maven, jdk11

На работе дали новый комп и я установил jdk, intellij idea и maven. После того старался поднять проект но maven не может качать зависимостей. И во всех проектах та же проблема.
Проверил settings.xml и maven переустановил, mvn clean install, очистил кэш, reimport пробовал эти но не помогло.

Вот так выглядит во всех проектах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>*****</groupId>
<artifactId>***</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sed</name>
<description>***********</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!--Security tagLibs-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate 2nd level cache-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--JAVA11-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--JAVA9/10 Legacy-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.3.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.3.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.3.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>javax.activation</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>activation</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>1.1.1</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--JAVA9/10 Legacy-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j2html</groupId>
        <artifactId>j2html</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-mask-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
        <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
        <version>1.5-beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JasperReportServer integration dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jaspersoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperserver</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>********</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaspercipher</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Ошибки

```
Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-common:4.1.31.Final

Cannot resolve com.querydsl:querydsl-core:4.2.1

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:1.9

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve net.sourceforge.barbecue:barbecue:1.5-beta1

Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.7

Cannot resolve org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25

Cannot resolve javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:1.3

Cannot resolve org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:2.6.2

Cannot resolve com.fasterxml:classmate:1.4.0

Cannot resolve com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.1

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve com.jaspersoft:jasperserver:7.5.0

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:1.9

Cannot resolve org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6

Cannot resolve org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2

Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:5.1.2.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:2.2

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.15

Cannot resolve javax.activation:activation:1.1

Cannot resolve stax:stax:1.2.0

Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-el-api:9.0.13

Cannot resolve avalon-framework:avalon-framework-impl:4.2.0

Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.31.Final

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:1.9

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.2.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.jfree:jfreechart:1.0.19

Cannot resolve org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:1.9

Cannot resolve com.querydsl:querydsl-codegen:4.2.1

Cannot resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9

Cannot resolve xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01

Cannot resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:2.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-constants:1.9

Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.13

Cannot resolve com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1

Cannot resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:1.9

Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.31.Final

Cannot resolve org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.4.2

Cannot resolve org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.3.3

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.13

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:1.9

Cannot resolve javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final

Cannot resolve xalan:serializer:2.7.2

Cannot resolve net.minidev:accessors-smart:1.2

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:1.9

Cannot resolve org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.11.1

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:1.9

Cannot resolve commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2

Cannot resolve com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-oxm:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.reflections:reflections:0.9.9

Cannot resolve org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:1.8

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve commons-io:commons-io:1.3.1

Cannot resolve com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:3.0.7

Cannot resolve com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js6

Cannot resolve com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.2.0

Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.1.2.RELEASE

Cannot resolve javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2

Cannot resolve org.jboss:jandex:2.0.5.Final

Cannot resolve org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1

Cannot resolve javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.9

Cannot resolve com.j2html:j2html:1.3.0

Cannot resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3

Cannot resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.1

Cannot resolve org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.3.7.Final

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-i18n:1.9

Cannot resolve com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.2.1

Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.31.Final

Cannot resolve commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6

Cannot resolve net.sf.barcode4j:barcode4j:2.0

Cannot resolve com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2

Cannot resolve com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0

Cannot resolve com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1

Cannot resolve org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.3.7.Final

Cannot resolve kg.itservice.gp:jaspercipher:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:5.1.2.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.7.Final

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve junit:junit:4.12

Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.1.2.RELEASE

Cannot resolve net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.6

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:1.9

Cannot resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.4

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.28

Cannot resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.9.5

Cannot resolve stax:stax-api:1.0.1

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.webjars.bower:jquery-mask-plugin:1.14.10

Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.7

Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jsp-api:9.0.13

Cannot resolve org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.3

Cannot resolve org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.3.7.Final

Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.7

Cannot resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3

Cannot resolve org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5

Cannot resolve org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1

Cannot resolve net.minidev:json-smart:2.3

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.1.1.Final

Cannot resolve org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.23

Cannot resolve org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4

Cannot resolve com.h2database:h2:1.4.197

Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.9.7

Cannot resolve com.mysema.codegen:codegen:0.6.8

Cannot resolve org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.25.0.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:9.0.13

Cannot resolve javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1

Cannot resolve net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.5

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve com.google.guava:guava:18.0

Cannot resolve org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.3

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.31.Final

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve antlr:antlr:2.7.7

Cannot resolve org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.4.Final

Cannot resolve org.springframework.session:spring-session-core:2.1.2.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve xalan:xalan:2.7.2

Cannot resolve org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.23

Cannot resolve org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.13.Final

Cannot resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.7

Cannot resolve org.javassist:javassist:3.23.1-GA

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:1.9

Cannot resolve org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:1.3.3

Cannot resolve com.ibm.icu:icu4j:57.1

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-orm:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.2

Cannot resolve commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-expression:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.31.Final

Cannot resolve xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:1.3.04

Cannot resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2

Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.13

Cannot resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-tx:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0

Cannot resolve org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final

Cannot resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1

Cannot resolve org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:1.9

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.1.1.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-test:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve commons-digester:commons-digester:2.1

Cannot resolve org.dom4j:dom4j:2.1.1

Cannot resolve com.infradna.tool:bridge-method-annotation:1.13

Cannot resolve org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis:2.1.2.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.1.2.RELEASE

Cannot resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

Cannot resolve io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.1.3.RELEASE

Cannot resolve com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:0.2.4

Cannot resolve net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.7.0

Cannot resolve ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
```

Мой maven

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Мой jdk

```
java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Настораживает слово "дали". Предполагаю, что на работе. Предполагаю, что там какой-то хитрый VPN или внутренняя сеть, с хитрыми доступами и разрешениями.

Зайдите командной строке в папку проекта и выполните `mvn -X clean install`
Будет чуть больше вывода и чуть более понятно что там *Cannot resolve*

Comment: Может стоит обратиться к тем, кто дал этот ноут? или же к команде...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1][[image: Перезапуск Maven]]

Очистите Maven и обновите его, чтобы он заново подтянул зависимости как указано на скриншоте

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]